# How to get a war artifact into ear artifact in a gradle multimodule project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy, dependencies

### Context:

A gradle multimodule project consisting of subproject **A**, subproject **B**.

### Artifacts:

**A** produces `a.ear`.
**B** produces `b.jar` and `b.war`.

### build.gradle

##### **A**

```
plugins {
   id 'java-library'
   id 'ear'
}

dependencies {
   deploy project(':B')
}
```

### Results

```
A
|-build
   |-...
   |-libs
   |   |-a.ear
   |   |   |-...
   |   |   |-b.jar
```

## The Problem

What I actually need is **b.war** to be present into **a.ear**. So where the **b.jar** is in **a.ear** should also be **b.war**, but that one is missing.

### What I assume

There should be somehow a way where I declare the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   deploy project(':B')
}
```

to specify that I want a war artifact from subproject **B**. Of course I am open also to other suggestions of how to put the **b.war** into **a.ear**.

Comment: Why would you want that? The jar and war should contain the same classes. Maybe include the war *instead of* the jar.

Comment: So that is the problem, that the war is not included into the ear. It is included only the b.jar, but not b.war.

Comment: So adjust the Gradle task that's building the jar to build the war instead. You shouldn't need the jar at all.

Comment: When only the b.war is created gradle does not put in a.ear the b.war, so it's exactly the same if it creates both the b.war and b.jar.